# combine jQuery on ready + change

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

i want to change this line of code to run ready and change

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(function(e) {
```

editing the line to

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').ready(function(e) {
```

fixes my problem, but i still need .change function

the whole code:

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(function(e) {
if (jQuery('#form_auction_type').val() == '2') {
jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').show();
} else {
jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').hide();
```

how can i put ready and change in the same line!!

Comment: You can't put it on the same line!  Simply put your `change` handler _inside_ of the DOM ready event handler.

Comment: can you show me example please i'm still a noobie

Comment: The posted answer below by Adeneo shows what I just said.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change it to

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#form_auction_type').on('change', function() {
        $('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').toggle($('#form_auction_type').val() == '2');
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: This should do exactly what @Ahmed wants - it sets up the code to execute on a change event, and also triggers that change event - but it won't happen until the document.ready event.  Good answer.

Comment: TL;DR: Just append `change()` to the original change event listener, so it triggers it at the beginning, once.